# NPM call bash script with multiple arguments

Tags: bash, npm, npm-scripts

I have created a bash script to automate the git release flow. This script takes one or multiple branch names as argument.

I can call the script in the terminal with: `./releaseGit.sh -b branch1 -b branch2`

But I want to use the script with npm. My current package.json contains:

```
"scripts": {
   (other scripts..)
   "git-release": "scripts/releaseGit.sh -b $*"
}
```

But with this configuration I can only pass one branch as argument to the script. How can I change that?

works:

```
npm run git-release -b only-one-branch
```

Doesn't work:

```
npm run git-release -b first-branch -b second-branch
```

Comment: You need `--` when passing arguments - remove the placeholder in scripts and call `npm run git-release -- -b first-branch -b second-branch`. See [the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script).

Comment: It works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Package.json:

```
scripts: {
  test: "sh init.sh"
}
```

Pass args:

```
npm run test -- a b c
```